# Using slick slider as navigation for another slider that opens upon ajax load method call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, slick.js

The slider I'm using is slick slider. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I have a slider on a page that when an image is clicked, opens a lightbox (via ajax load method) that contains another slider with the same images that are in the same order, but larger and not cropped so the audience can view the full-sized images.

I want the user to be able to navigate the slider that is on the main page by selecting the nav-dots, click on an image, and have that same image be the active image inside the lightbox slider once it has been loaded.

## Problem

The problem I am having is that because the '.lightbox-slider' is not yet loaded, the '.home-slider' cannot tell it which slide to go to.

### HTML for main page slider

```
<div class="media-slider slider single-item-rtl tall-slider" dir="rtl">
    <div class="article-media select-media slick-active">
       <img src="/images/test/16-example.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article-media select-media">
       <img class="slider-img" src="/images/test/17-example.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article-media select-media">
        <img class="slider-img" src="/images/test/18-example.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article-media select-media">
        <img class="slider-img" src="/images/test/19-example.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### HTML for slider that is displayed inside lightbox

```
<div class="lighbox-slider">
    <div class="article-media select-media slick-active">
       <img src="/images/test/16-example.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article-media select-media">
       <img class="slider-img" src="/images/test/17-example.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article-media select-media">
        <img class="slider-img" src="/images/test/18-example.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="article-media select-media">
        <img class="slider-img" src="/images/test/19-example.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS for both lightboxes

```
var load_slider = function() {
  $('.home-slider').slick({
    rtl: true,
    dots: true, 
    arrows: false, 
    focusOnSelect: true,
    asNavFor: '.lightbox-slider'
  });
}; 

var load_lightbox_slider = function() {
  $('.lightbox-slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    speed: 300,
    fade: false,
    arrows: true, 
    cssEase: 'linear',
    asNavFor: '.home-slider'
 });
};
```

### JS used to open the lightbox and load lightbox slider

```
$(".select-media").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("article-media")) {

        $(".display_media").load("/images/toggle-media/" + $(this).attr("data-example"));

      $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
          load_lightbox_slider();
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave this as a comment, but bc of Stack Overflow rules, I have to do this as a response.

First, I'd recommend using `.on` instead of `.click` because you can actually specify the `if` statement in your event handler:

```
$(".select-media").on('click', '.display_media', function(event, xhr, settings) {
  // …
})
```

Now, as for the event itself, I'm not completely sure from the code provided, but it seems like the document is not loaded yet. From what I can tell, here are some possible options:

A) Have you tried wrapping this in a document.ready function? It may not have loaded everything yet?

B) Try calling the `load_lightbox_slider` from the beginning, but add a display none, or opacity: 0 on the .lightbox-slider class and change it to whatever display type/opacity 100% on click.

C) Use promises for your AJAX call, and mount the slider only after you know you have the data.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just move the slider to the current position after it is loaded in the lightbox?

First get the current slide from the small slider, pass it over to the initalisation of the new slider and jump to the same slide:

```js
    function load_lightbox_slider(currentslide){
 
         $('.lightbox-slider').slick({
            dots: false,
            speed: 300,
            fade: false,
            arrows: true, 
            cssEase: 'linear',
            asNavFor: '.home-slider'
        });
        // Move the new slider to the new position
        $('.lightbox-slider').slick('slickGoTo', currentslide);
    
    }
    
    
$(".select-media").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("article-media")) {

      $(".display_media").load("/images/toggle-media/" + $(this).attr("data-example"));

      $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
         // Get the current slide
          var currentSlide = $('.home-slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
          // create new slider instance
          load_lightbox_slider(currentSlide);
      });
    }
});
```